# Dynamically update lines in Highcharts time series chart

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, streaming, time-series, multiline

Here I'm working on Highcharts time series chart with live streaming data, based on the sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bg6q3wh/10/). In the fiddle there shows 4 lines named as input1, input2, input3, & input 4 and it is updated with live random data but in my actual project the input values are updated via MQTT. In actual project, sometimes, when we push streaming data, there will be increase or decrease in no: of inputs (such as input5, input6 like wise). So how can we add new line or remove line dynamically in time series chart with streaming data.

javascript code :

```
$(function() {
$(document).ready(function() {
Highcharts.setOptions({
  global: {
    useUTC: false
  }
});

$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load: function() {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series;
        var length = series.length;
        setInterval(function() {

          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            a0 = Math.random();
          a1 = Math.random();
          a2 = Math.random();
          series[0].addPoint([x, Math.random()], true, true);
          for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            series[i].addPoint([x, Math.random()], false, true);
          }
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPixelInterval: 150
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Value'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'input1',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random()
        });
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }, {
    name: 'input2',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random()
        });
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }, {
    name: 'input3',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random()
        });
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }, {
    name: 'input4',
    data: (function() {
      // generate an array of random data
      var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

      for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
        data.push({
          x: time + i * 1000,
          y: Math.random()
        });
      }
      return data;
    }())
  }]
});
});
});
```

Comment: Shijo you can try like this, http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleauto/8bg6q3wh/12/.. else in setInterval, fetch data from api by using ajax and those data you can pass.

Comment: @prudviraju he wants to know how to add series and not just points, he already has the example for adding points.
you'll have to check if the data returned from api is a point or a series. if it is a series, you can use [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries)

Comment: You can [remove](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.remove) / [add](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries) series by API functions, the key is find a condition which checks if series should be added or removed.

Comment: I have tried with @prudvi-raju example [http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleauto/8bg6q3wh/12/]. I also want to verify that if the incoming point (streaming data) is already in series array then add that incomig point else delete that line point by point(ie,if the incoming data doesn't contain a point already in series array, then that line should be deleted line by line). If the incoming data is new one then it should be added to series Array(input5.input6 like that).